# Functions not being called python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Function is not being called inside another function:

```
ch = False
while not ch:
     print("""
        1. Make a User
        2. Login in and Play
        3. Quit

   """)
     a = input("What would you like to do: ")
     if a == '1':
        un_maker()
     elif a == '2':
        player1Login()
     elif a == '3':
        input('\nEnter to exit...\n')
        quit()
```

Where when `a` is 2, it should move on to `player1Login()`, it does but it does not go to the next function inside the `player1Login()`.

The code for `player1Login()` and the function it's supposed to run:

```
 def player1Login():
     """ Login for player 1 """
     user1 = input("Please enter your usernames[Caps sensitive]:  ") # Asking the 
     user to input there username
     pass1 = input("Please also enter your password[Caps sensitive]: ") # Asking the user to input there password
     verfi1(user1, pass1)

  def verfi1(user1, pass1):
     """ Verfications of the user """
     with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # makes 'reader' the csv reader of file 'f'
        for row in reader: # Looking at rows/records inside the file
            if user1 in row: # Looks for username inside the row
                if pass1 in row[1]:
                     print("Player 1 Confirmed") 
                     player2Login()
                elif pass1 != row[1] or reader == '':
                     print("""You have entered the wrong Username/Password for Player 1
                              This could be due to:
                              1. Inputed the wrong username/password
                              2. Inputed the wrong case in username/password
                              3. Inputed username/password that does not exit
                           """)
                     break
            else:
                 #print("Reader")
                 next(reader)
```

Basically, the code should output when `a` is 2, `player1Login()` then move onto `verfi1()` function however it does not, it just goes back to the menu.

Answer Found:

```
def menu():
    ch = False
    optin = 0
    while not ch :
           print("""
                1. Make a User
                2. Login in and Play
                3. Quit
                """)
           optin = input("What would you like to do: ")
           if optin == '1':
               un_maker()
           elif optin == '2':
               player1Login()
           elif optin == '3':
               input('\nEnter to exit...\n')
               quit()

def player1Login():
""" Login for player 1 """
    user1 = input("Please enter your usernames[Caps sensitive]:  ") 
    pass1 = input("Please also enter your password[Caps sensitive]: ")
    boop(user1, pass1)

def boop(user1, pass1):
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if pass1 in row[1] and user1 in row[0]:
                 print("Username and Password found, Player 1 Confirmed")
                 player2Login(user1)
            elif pass1 not in row[1] and user1 not in row[0] and row[0] == '' :
                 print("Player Not found / Password incorrect")
                 menu()
```

Comment: You have nothing inside the `for row in reader:` loop. Is the next line supposed to be indented inside it?

Comment: Yes its supposed to be indented, i cant get used to the way to do code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You skip lines with `next` and therefore jump over each other user in you `data.csv` file. This can lead to  that `if user1 in row` is never true even though `user1` is in your file but happens to be on a skipped line.

Your code:

```
for row in reader: # Looking at rows/records inside the file
    if user1 in row: # Looks for username inside the row
        if pass1 in row[1]:
            print("Player 1 Confirmed") 
            player2Login()
        elif pass1 != row[1] or reader == '':
            print("""You have entered the wrong Username/Password for Player 1
            This could be due to:
            1. Inputed the wrong username/password
            2. Inputed the wrong case in username/password
            3. Inputed username/password that does not exit
            """)
            break
    else:
        next(reader) # this skips the next
```

Remove the `else`clause because `for row in reader` already goes over all lines.

Comment: Well i tried this before but the code just looks at the lines without doing anything, which is why i added next(reader) to get it to move on to the next line and read whats there. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Make user the user name you type is in your csv file.

Comment: Yes,the same username is typed, which the program skips when trying to find the same username and outputs the elif statement.

Comment: I've gotten it to work so thanks for the help. Also I'll update to show the answer